# Hosting WCF service in IIS cause an error "Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application..."

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis

**Error: Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.**

I have seen this error has been posted in StackOverflow and other websites a lot.
But all of them wanted to show a MessageBox or a DialogBox in their services.

I haven't written any line of code to display a Form or a MessageBox in my WCF Service.

I have also seen that somebody had said this error could be because of an internal error happening in your service and because it wants to show the error message, you will get this error. I think this one is more probable in my case as I have hosted my WCF Service in my own computer (Which is Windows 7) without any problem. It works fine. But when I host the service In a Production Environment (which is a Windows Server 2008) with exactly same configuration, I get this error.

How can I see what's wrong inside my service? what is the dialog that wants to be shown?

[image]

UPDATE:

> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message
>   reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version,
>   FaultConverter faultConverter)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   Khorramshahr_Ins.FingerPrintWebService.IIdentifyFingerPrint.IdentifyFinger(IdentifyFingerRequest
>   request)    at
>   Khorramshahr_Ins.FingerPrintWebService.IdentifyFingerPrintClient.IdentifyFinger(IdentifyFingerRequest
>   request) in C:\PROJECTS\Production V1.0\ImportExport\Production
>   V1\Fermat.ImportExport.Presentation\Service
>   References\FingerPrintWebService\Reference.vb:line 328    at
>   Khorramshahr_Ins.frmDeliverDocuments.Callback(IAsyncResult ar) in
>   C:\PROJECTS\Production V1.0\ImportExport\Production
>   V1\Fermat.ImportExport.Presentation\Operator\frmDeliverDocuments.vb:line
>   63    at Khorramshahr_Ins.frmDeliverDocuments.btnVerify_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) in C:\PROJECTS\Production
>   V1.0\ImportExport\Production
>   V1\Fermat.ImportExport.Presentation\Operator\frmDeliverDocuments.vb:line
>   47    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs kevent)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessKeyEventArgs(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessKeyMessage(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmKeyChar(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr
>   hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunDialog(Form form)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()    at
>   Khorramshahr_Ins.TotalListWindow.btnDeliverDocuments_OnClick(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) in C:\PROJECTS\Production
>   V1.0\ImportExport\Production
>   V1\Fermat.ImportExport.Presentation\Report\TotalListWindow.xaml.vb:line
>   185    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   EnhancedGlassButton.GlassButton.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)    at
>   EnhancedGlassButton.GlassButton.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons
>   button, Int32 clicks)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr
>   hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)    at
>   MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame
>   frame)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
>   at System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox)    at
>   System.Windows.Window.Show()    at System.Windows.Window.ShowDialog()

Comment: The method IdentifyFinger(...) will surely open a dialog that requests the user to put his finger on some sensor. Did you host the same service in the IIS on your Windows 7 machine?

Comment: No! it doesn't open any dialog as I said. Yes it works on IIS of my own machine which is windows 7

Comment: Maybe different fingerprint hardware or driver?

Comment: the driver/home made wrapper of the finger/dongle might show some dialog box since apparently the dongle was designed for desktop applications. You may need to inspect the call stack or post it here so we may possiblly find out solution/work around to catch the error without allowing the dongle driver to show dialog. The worse scenario is that you may have to find another dongle not so rude.

Comment: @AndyH it doesn't have dongle. it just have a License file which I installed that as well. I added Stack Trace

Answer (score 1):

So apparently this FingerPrintWebService called by your broker service supports callback.

> C:\PROJECTS\Production V1.0\ImportExport\Production V1\Fermat.ImportExport.Presentation\Service References\FingerPrintWebService\Reference.vb:line 328 at Khorramshahr_Ins.frmDeliverDocuments.Callback(IAsyncResult ar) in C:\PROJECTS\Production V1.0\ImportExport\Production V1\Fermat.ImportExport.Presentation\Operator\frmDeliverDocuments.vb:line 63 at

and the callback could be invoking a WinForm or dialog -- which in turn require message pump, which is odd in a service.

It was working on Win7 probably because on Win7 it did not run through this call stack; besides, Win7 and Server 2008 have different default settings. Since Server 2008, MS had made a lot changes in security for services, particularly fixed some loopholes of services calling UI.

Anyway, you might need to reconsider your overall design. And if you want to be alerted about error, use one of the trace listeners in BCL, say, EventLogTraceListener, or other trace listeners in http://essentialdiagnostics.codeplex.com/